# Error CS0029 que corresponde a tipos de variables en el lenguaje C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

Cordial saludo equipo, quiero pedirles el siguiente favor con unos errores que me aparecen en un código que tengo escrito en una aplicación escrita en C# , el error que me aparece son los siguientes:

```
Precio = Convert.ToDecimal(dr["Correo"], new CultureInfo("es-CO")),
```

Aquí el error que me aparece es el `CS0029` que dice:

```
“No se puede convertir implícitamente el tipo ‘decimal’ en ‘string’ ”.
```

En la siguiente línea de código

```
Cantidad = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Cantidad"].ToString()),
```

Me aparece este error:

Igualmente es el  `CS0029` pero en este caso dice:

```
“No se puede convertir implícitamente el tipo ‘int’ en ‘string’ ”.
```

De manera similar me aparece en la línea

```
Total = Convert.ToDecimal(dr["Total"], new CultureInfo("es-CO")),
```

el siguiente error:

`CS0029` pero en este caso dice

```
“No se puede convertir implícitamente el tipo ‘decimal’ en ‘string’ .
```

Yo no sé por qué me aparecen estos errores.

Muchas gracias por la colaboración que me puedan brindar.

Comment: Precio.. cantidad.. son de tipo string?

Comment: Defines `Precio` ¿desde `correo`?

Answer (score 1):

Este tipo de error es generado porque estas intentando hacer una conversión de tipo de dato implícita, para solucionar tu problema necesitas convertir explícitamente el tipo de datos. Las conversiones explícitas se realizan mediante la conversión. La conversión es el término que se usa para describir la conversión de un tipo de datos a otro de una forma como esta:

```
int i = 50;
long lng = 100;
i = (int) lng;   // Conversión entera.
```

Puedas intentar probar colocando el tipo de dato dentro del paréntesis `()` para castear la clase y no generar errores.

Comment: Estás seguro que eso funciona en el caso del op?

Comment: Las conversiones explicitas o implícitas deben existir, en tu ejemplo `long` cuenta con una conversión explicita. No obstante no existe conversión (explicita, ni implícita) de `int` y `decimal` hacia `String` que es el problema de la Pregunta